# Vuepress dynamic routes and render as page?

Tags: vue.js, routes, vuepress

I use vuepress as a mixed solution of static generated pages and dynamic pages in the SPA approach. The dynamic data source is a large database server, hence it can not use the [additionalPages](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/plugin/option-api.html#additionalpages) feature introduced in vurepress 1.x. That means dynamic routes was added using enhanceApp.js as below. Dynamic pages are rendered with extended layouts to share same page structure (header, footer).

```
// Foo is a layout component extends from Layout.vue
import Foo from './layouts/Foo.vue' 

export default ({
  Vue, // the version of Vue being used in the VuePress app
  options, // the options for the root Vue instance
  router, // the router instance for the app
  siteData // site metadata
}) => {
  router.addRoutes([
    { path: '/foo/:id', component: Foo },
  ]);
}
```

It works, however the `layouts/Foo.vue` is a component. It missing frontmatter, markdown syntax like normal markdown page does. The question is how to load a markdown page and pass to routes as component?

Answer (score 0):

I'm still new to Vuepress, but I come across [this comment](https://github.com/vuejs/vuepress/blob/c17c70e96af5542edba86032c22cc67348251d78/packages/%40vuepress/core/lib/node/Page.js#L133) in the source code that might be able to help you.

> When Vue SFCs are source files, make them as layout components directly

I haven't finished reading all source code, so I'm not very sure I understand it correctly. But I guess when Vuepress find a vue component, it will not render it like a markdown file. It assumes you have your own style inside the `.vue` file. So I think that may be why you are missing what normal markdown page has.

However, if you need to mix a dynamic data source with static pages, you can try to [use Vue in markdown](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/guide/using-vue.html#using-vue-in-markdown) to get what you want to achieve.